# Adding scroll wheel movement to a webpage

Tags: javascript

In the below presentation I can scroll through the slides with the scroll wheel.

http://dimroc.github.com/reveal.js-threejs/#/

This is the source code demonstration for the presentation below. The scroll wheel is not functional to go through the slides.

My question is **How do I make the scroll wheel functioning as an arrow key in my presentations?**

http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

Comment: I am able to go north and south with my mousewheel...

Comment: can you on this as well on this page? http://lab.hakim.se/reveal-js/#/

Comment: no....it only works for me (in chrome) at your first url (http://dimroc.github.com/reveal.js-threejs/#/)

Comment: yeah that's the solution i'm looking for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing `mouseWheel: true` in your `Reveal.initialize` method.